# How do you iterate over an object in a manner agnostic to whether it is a list or a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

As part of some of the code I am trying to write, I am trying to validate some user input before using it.  I would like to do something akin to the following that operates identically regardless of whether the collection is a list or a dictionary, preferably without having to always convert it into one of the two.

```
list_or_dict = {0:7, 1:12}  # or [7, 12]
for addr, value in list_or_dict.items():
    if addr > addr_max:
        raise Exception()
    if value > val_max:
        raise Exception()
```

Edit:

Just to be clear, I will only expect integer keys for dictionaries. Also, I want the indicies of a list to be an addr if only for consistency reasons.

Comment: why not have 2 validators, one for dictionaries and 1 for lists, with the main code testing types then dispatching? No conversion required and avoids the need for things like checking or error-trapping in the middle of the loop.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any way to have to avoid writing two similar validators. If there really isn't, then that is what I will do.

Comment: How is it possible that the input comes in those different forms? Seems rather odd.

Comment: What would you want to do with a list? Would list elements be analogous to dict keys, or values? ("agonistic" is pretty funny)

Comment: @BrianO list elements themselves would be analogous to values, with the indices of the list analogous to the keys

Comment: Do you want to access the indices of list elements? Your question doesn't mention that at all. If it had, I would have done things differently in my answer. Actually I wouldn't have answered at all, as the answer by @StefanPochmann already does what I would do.

Comment: @BrianO Yeah, I do if only for consistency reasons. I thought that the example would make that obvious, I guess I was wrong...

Comment: @StefanPochmann I am trying to use dictionaries as a sparse array, as sometimes allocating a dense array would be wasteful, (eg allocating 2^32 array elements). However, I also want to save space and computation time for when the array is dense (as I assume dicts are slower than lists).

Comment: Makes sense, though you probably should say as much in the question. If the "addresses" in dicts are guaranteed to be ints, validation doesn't become any more more complicated.

Comment: @BrianO I always struggle to figure out what stuff is necessary in the question and what is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `enumerate(list_or_dict)` or `list_or_dict.items()` depending on what it is. Then you have `(addr, value)` pairs in both cases and can use the same code.

```
>>> def check(list_or_dict):
        items = enumerate(list_or_dict) if isinstance(list_or_dict, list) else list_or_dict.items()
        for addr, value in items:
            print(addr, value)

>>> check({0:7, 1:12})
(0, 7)
(1, 12)
>>> check([7, 12])
(0, 7)
(1, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assume it's a `dict` and try to convert it to a `list`. If it fails, then you already have a `list`.

```
list_or_dict = {0:7, 1:12}  # or [7, 12]
try:
    list_or_dict = list(list_or_dict.items())
except AttributeError:
    list_or_dict = list(enumerate(list_or_dict))
# your processing
```

Note that this will only produce correct results if the dictionary version will always have integer keys starting at 0 and increasing by 1 with each item. Otherwise, you will have to find some other way of filling in these missing data. Also note that, if that is indeed a consistent pattern, instead of checking each key or index you can just check the length of the object. You can also use `any()` to streamline this (and you don't need `()` after `Exception`):

```
list_or_dict = {0:7, 1:12}  # or [7, 12]
try:
    list_or_dict = list(list_or_dict.values())
except AttributeError:
    pass
if len(list_or_dict) >= addr_max or any(value > val_max for value in list_or_dict):
    raise Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to have just a single loop. It uses a single iterator that gives successive `(addr, value)` pairs. If the parameter is a list, `addr` is always `None` and the `value`s are the successive list elements; if the parameter is a dict, `(addr, value)` are the dict's items. I'm assuming that elements of lists are analogous to the values of dicts; adjust accordingly if they're analogous to keys.

```
def handle_list_or_dict(ld):
    if isinstance(ld, list):
        ld_iter = ((None, value) for value in ld)
    else:
        ld_iter = ld.items()

    for addr, value in ld_iter:
        if addr is not None and addr > addr_max:
            raise Exception()
        if value > val_max:
            raise Exception()
        # Do what you really want to do... Here we just print:
        print(addr, value)
```

Take it for a spin:

```
>>> addr_max = 2; val_max = 12
>>> handle_list_or_dict({0:7, 1:12})
0 7
0 12

>>> handle_list_or_dict([7, 12])
None 7
None 12
```

Exception-raising:

```
>>> addr_max = 0
>>> handle_list_or_dict([7, 12])    # won't raise
None 7
None 12

>>> handle_list_or_dict({0:7, 1:12})  # will raise
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Exception
```

Changing the upper bounds to `addr_max = 2; val_max = 10`, both lists and dicts raise for values out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle lists and dictionaries separately by checking the type. Here's an example:

```
test_cases = [ {1337:'foo'}, [1337, 'foo'] ]

for case in test_cases:
    if type(case) is dict:
        for k, v in case.items():
            print(k, v)
    elif type(case) is list:
        for i in case:
            print(i)
```

Comment: [```isinstance```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) might be a better choice than ```type```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `if` *operator* at the beginning of the loop to grab the intended iterator:

```
def agnostic(x):
    for y in x if isinstance(x,list) else x.items():
        print(y)
```

For example,

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> agnostic(x)
1
2
3
>>> d = {0:1,2:7}
>>> agnostic(d)
(0, 1)
(2, 7)
```

Note that you can replace `x.items()` by either `x.keys()` or `x.values()` in the definition of the agnostic iterator, depending on exactly what part of the dictionary (if that is what it is) you want to iterate over.